# Noting discrepancies between scheduled and actual attendance of sessions

Tags: c#, performance, object-oriented, database

I ask as I'm mostly self taught, and don't have a team to be able to get experience/challenge or ask.

**The Requirement**

I have a register per week. (ie the kind you mark attendance on), with sub sessions (known here as services).  Ie, Morning, afternoon, evening etc.
It is indicated whether someone is scheduled and/or whether they attended.  (Someone can attend a different one to which they were scheduled.)

Coming from a UI, which posts a whole register; Into a API, through a BLL, into a repo, then a SQL Server database.
  A Register has attendees. Attendees have Services.
Register → Attendees → Services.

**Existing/Problematic**

The existing method has issues, update & insert statements buried within two loops, which I know smells, hence I'm trying to remedy, but I'm not sure of the best way to do it.

Currently it was designed to…

- Loop through the Attendees;

  - Then within that, loop through the Services.
  - Then within that:

    - Update the scheduled Service and
    - Insert if someone attended a different Service.

With upto 50 people per register week, and typically 5 possible Services per day, a couple of database hits per one, we quickly have over 500 hits on the database per register save. This is obviously hitting the database a lot!

**First thoughts**

I'm trying to get my classes to adhere more to the SRP.  What I was considering, in the BLL project, was this.  (Where these are 2 lists of Services, the BLL getting the current register state, and the one submitted to the API call.)
Which exposed something like:

```
public interface IRegisterChangeComparer
{
    List<Service> GetAdded();
    List<Service> GetRemoved();
    List<Service> GetChangedServices();
}

public class RegisterChangeComparer : IRegisterChangeComparer
{
    private List<Service> SubmittedServices;
    private List<Service> ExistingServices;

    public RegisterChangeComparer(List<Service> submittedServices, List<Service> existingServices)
    {
        SubmittedServices = submittedServices;
        ExistingServices = existingServices;
    }

    public List<Service> GetAdded()
    {
        List<Service> newlyAdded = new List<Service>();
        foreach (Service service in SubmittedServices.Where(s => !s.IsScheduled))
        {
            // Compare on Date, Service Type
            if (!ExistingServices.Exists(e => e.ServiceDate == service.ServiceDate && e.TypeId == service.TypeId))
            {
                newlyAdded.Add(service);
            }
        }
        return newlyAdded;
    }

    public List<Service> GetRemoved()
    {
        List<Service> removedServices = new List<Service>();
        foreach (Service service in ExistingServices.Where(s => !s.IsScheduled))
        {
            // Compare on Date, Service Type
            if (SubmittedServices.Exists(e => e.ServiceDate == service.ServiceDate && e.TypeId == service.TypeId))
            {
                removedServices.Add(service);
            }
        }
        return removedServices;
    }

    public List<Service> GetChangedServices()
    {
        List<Service> changedServices = new List<Service>();
        foreach (Service service in SubmittedServices)
        {
            //Find matching record from database data
            Service matchedService = ExistingServices.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ServiceDate == service.ServiceDate && e.TypeId == service.TypeId);

            if (matchedService == null) continue;

            if (service.IsAttended != matchedService.IsAttended && service.IsScheduled) 
            {
                changedServices.Add(service);
            }
        }
        return changedServices;
    }
}
```

Then pass that to the repo accordingly to save, but with grouped/less hits on the database.

---

Here is the Service Class.  It probably ought to be using the Id for find/comparison.

```
public class Service
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ServiceUserId { get; set; }
        public int SupplierId { get; set; }
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public DateTime ServiceDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Units { get; set; }
        public int PONumber { get; set; }
        public decimal Rate { get; set; }
        public bool IsScheduled { get; set; }
        public bool IsAttended { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdatedeDate { get; set; }
    }
```

---

Initially I'm after pointers to whether I'm going about it the right way or whether there's a better way to pursue.  Any particular patterns to choose.  I just want to improve and write better code.

Comment: There are no update & insert statements in the posted code

Comment: @paparazzi I was planning to then use the output from above, to pass into repository actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with all things said by @TopinFrassi and want to add some additional notes.

If you have the same code repeated multiple times extract it to a method. Define method like this

```
private static Service FindService(IEnumerable<Service> services, Service service)
{
    return services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceDate == service.ServiceDate &&
                                        s.TypeId == service.TypeId;
}
```

It will simplify all your methods. Also if you will return `IEnumerable<Service>` instead of `List<Service>` they can be even more simpler. For example, `GetAdded` will be

```
public IEnumerable<Service> GetAdded()
{
    foreach (var service in SubmittedServices.Where(s => !s.IsScheduled))
    {
        if (FindService(ExistingServices, service) == null)
        {
            yield return service;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can use LINQ:

```
public IEnumerable<Service> GetAdded()
{
    return from service in SubmittedServices
           where !service.IsScheduled &&
                 FindService(ExistingServices, service) == null)
           select service;
}
```

And another two methods:

```
public IEnumerable<Service> GetRemoved()
{
    return from service in ExistingServices
           where !service.IsScheduled &&
                 FindService(SubmittedServices, service) != null)
           select service;
}

public IEnumerable<Service> GetChangedServices()
{
    return from service in SubmittedServices
           let matchedService = FindService(ExistingServices, service)
           where matchedService != null &&
                 service.IsAttended != matchedService.IsAttended &&
                 service.IsScheduled
           select service;
}
```

Comment: I had wondered about splitting it out further as you have. Perhaps I need stop shying away creating many small classes.

Comment: @DavidC Wise decomposing is one of the keys to great architecture of a program, so don't shy to do it :)

Comment: Would you keep the FindService in that class, or create another separate class (And interface)?

Comment: If you don't suppose `FindService` will be used anywhere else in your program it is OK to keep it in the `RegisterChangeComparer`. If someday you will need this method from another place of your code then move it to a static helper class. You can even make it extension method for `IEnumerable<Service>` and be able to use it like this: `ExistingServices.FindService(service)`.

Comment: The FindServiceMethod cannot return  bool, as it's returning a Service

Answer (score 5):

First, I'd like to say that you're pretty well informed for a self-taught programmer. Still, there are some things to work on.

> IRegisterChangeComparer

```
public interface IRegisterChangeComparer
{
    List<Service> GetAdded();
    List<Service> GetRemoved();
    List<Service> GetChangedServices();
}
```

You should never expose a `List`. In fact, in most cases you never want to expose a concrete type when it comes to data structures. Since you return a list, I assume the said list won't be modified by the caller. So you should return `IEnumerable<Service>`. This limits the ways a user of your class can screw up your code (as you can't add/remove/insert/etc. from an IEnumerable<> without casting it, then it's just asking for trouble).

```
public interface IRegisterChangeComparer
{
    IEnumerable<Service> GetAdded();
    IEnumerable<Service> GetRemoved();
    IEnumerable<Service> GetChangedServices();
}
```

> RegisterChangeComparer fields

Field members are supposed to be `camelCased`, which means `ExistingServices` should be `existingServices`. Why? To easily differentiate them from the properties. You could make your fields `readonly`, this way they can't be modifier afer they've been initialized in your constructor. (You could still Add/Remove/etc.. from the list, but the reference cannot be changed). Now, if I look at your code, I see that these lists are never used as lists. I mean that you never use methods/properties that are specific to the `List<>`, only extension methods defined for `IEnumerable<>`. You know what that means? It means you should declare a `IEnumerable<Service>` instead of a `List<Service>` in your fields. If you think you might want to alter these lists later, you should declare a `ICollection<Service`.

```
private readonly IEnumerable<Service> existingServices;
private readonly IEnumerable<Service> submittedServices;
```

> RegisterChangeComparer constructor

First, you should change your parameters to `IEnumerable<>` for reasons I explained earlier. Second, since your class is public, it means "anyone" can create an instance of `RegisterChangeComparer`. That means the constructor needs to be "dumb proofed". You should **always** check your entry parameters for `null` in `public` methods/constructor/etc.

```
public RegisterChangeComparer(IEnumerable<Service> submittedServices, IEnumerable<Service> existingServices)
{
    if(submittedServices == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(submittedServices);
    if(existingServices == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(existingServices);

    //We use "this" for the compiler (and you) to make a difference between the parameter and the field
    this.submittedServices = submittedServices;
    this.existingServices = existingServices;
}
```

> RegisterChangeComparer methods

Now, let's get real. `Exists` isn't an efficient method. It's very slow. I don't have your `Service` class, which is sad because it'd be helpful at the moment. The question is, what defines the identity of a `Service`? **If** the identity if defined by `TypeID` and `ServiceDate` (meaning that if two services have the same ID and service date, they must be the same `Service`), you could override the `Equals` and `GetHashcode` methods of the `Service` class. Then, you could use an `HashSet<>` data structure inside your class (Instead of `IEnumerable`) to use the `Contains` method, which is far faster. Since this is all hypothetical, I don't want to go in too much details.

If this sounds unclear to you, I recommend reading on data structures. Each structure has pros and cons when it comes to its data. For example, the `HashSet` is very fast to see if it already contains an object.

This is all I can do with the information that you provided.

Comment: Does the overall approach of using a separate class to do the comparison feel right? I know in all cases I'll need to always know added/removed/updated. All 3.

Comment: I have now added the Service class above.